# Where does Visual Studio save code blocks that are dragged on the Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets, toolbox

You can drag and drop code blocks from the Codeeditor to the Toolbox of VisualStudio, but where does Visual Studio save those code blocks.

Are they globally available (for other projects) or only available in the solution/project they are dragged?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any code blocks that you drag to the Toolbox are stored in your [Visual Studio settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx) file. The default path to that file is under your "My Documents" folder:

```
..\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings
```

but of course, the exact location can be specified from the Options dialog in Visual Studio.

They are globally available for all projects in the applicable language. For example, if you create a code snippet in a C# project, it will be available for any C# projects that you create. However, it will *not* be available in a VB.NET project.

Also note that you can rename the individual snippets by right-clicking on them in the Toolbox, and selecting "Rename Item" from the context menu.

But there is a better and much more powerful way to manage code snippets rather than dragging them to your Toolbox. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2007/12/13/did-you-know-how-to-browse-code-snippets-and-add-new-ones-106/) on Sara Ford's blog (a great resource for tips and tricks relating to VS).

Comment: For me, on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019, the settings were at C:\Users\{YourUserId}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{CurrentVersion}\Settings