# Save and restore code clippings in Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I occasionally give demos and training at my office.  I have seen and used the technique where you drag code into the Visual Studio toolbox, so that you can later drag it into a code file during a demo.

My question:
I would like to be able to save and later reload tabs (each tab contains a demo/tutorial of code snips), so that I can get rid of clippings that I am not using, but still get them back.

Anyone know how to do that in Visual Studio?  (using VS 2012 Professional)

Note:  I have seen this article that describes where they are saved: [Where does Visual Studio save code blocks that are dragged on the Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872563/where-does-visual-studio-save-code-blocks-that-are-dragged-on-the-toolbox)

However, I am looking for a way to restore the snippets without restoring my entire set of vs settings.

Answer (score 4):

If you still have the tool box options available in VS, in theory you can export just the toolbox contents through **Tools > Import and Export Settings...** and import them later.

On the Import and Export Settings Wizard, choose **Export...**, click **Next >**. In the **Choose Settings to Export > Which settings do you want to export?** list, clear everything and then navigate to **General Settings > Toolbox** and select it. Then click **Next >** and save the file where you want.

Afterwards you should be able to restore just the Toolbox settings by using the **Tools > Import and Export Settings...** dialog.

Note that after I did an import I didn't see the snippet in the Toolbox, using VS 2017 V15.2, until I shut VS down and re-started it.